# Why did the designer make vector, map, and set functions in clojure?

Tags: function, collections, clojure

Rich made vector, map, and set functions, while list,  and sequence are not functions. 
Why cannot all these collections be function to make it consistent?

Further, why don't we make all these compose data as a function which maps position to it's internal data?

If we make all these compose data as function then there will be only function and atom data in clojure. This will minimize the fundamental elements in that language right?

I believe a minimal, best only 2, set of fundamental elements would make the language simpler, more expressive and more flexible.  Is this correct?

Comment: Is there a difference between a list and a sequence?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, It's difficult to answer questions about the state of someone else's mind in a way that you will be able to mark as "correct" or "incorrect" so it's difficult to answer this question objectively.

Comment: @BobJarvis sequence is an interface implemented by all the collection types, including list.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt, I agree that we can only speculate about what Rich thought, but if we view it as a question about the underlying rationale for these language design choices, does that make the question appropriate?  In many cases language design questions can only draw opinion-based answers, but in this case it seems that definitive, informative answers are possible.

Comment: I think, this question is quite important, because for me it looks like these data structures and their syntax is the biggest difference between Clojure and Common Lisp. I don't believe, it was just the mood of the Clojure author. I think, there is a clear reasoning why Clojure has these data structures. Even things like "to be more attractive for Python developers" could be a reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vectors, maps, and sets are all associative data structures. Maps are the most obvious; they simply associate arbitrary keys with arbitrary values. A vector can be thought of as a map whose key set must be the set of all nonnegative integers less than the vector's size. Finally, sets can be thought of as maps that map keys to themselves.

It's important to understand that the sequential nature of a vector and the associative nature of a vector are two orthogonal things. It's a data structure that's designed to be good at supporting both abstractions (to some extent; for instance, you can't efficiently insert at the beginning of a vector).

Lists are simpler than vectors; they are finite sequential data structures, nothing more. A list can't efficiently return the element at a particular index, so it doesn't expose that functionality as part of its core interface. Of course, you *can* get an element of a list by index using `nth`, but in that case, you're explicitly treating it as a sequence, *not* as an associative structure.

So to answer your question, the `IFn` implementations for vectors, maps, and sets are there because of the extremely close relationship between the idea of an associative data structure and the idea of a pure function. Lists and other sequences are not inherently associative, so for consistency, they do not implement `IFn`.

Comment: I checked set's property in Clojure seems it's not associative structure.  Run: (update #{1 2} 1 inc) you will get exception: PersistentHashSet can not cast to clojure.lang.Associative

Comment: @Shark By "associative", I didn't literally mean "implementing the [`Associative`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Associative.java) interface"; rather, I simply meant that that they efficiently support queries from keys to values. In Clojure, sets just happen to be handled as [a special case](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L746-L749), but that doesn't change the fact that they inherently support efficient lookup and lists don't.

Comment: thanks for show me the source code. Now can I say that it's a flaw on the Set's type definition in clojure? It suppose to implement Associative to make it consist?

Comment: @Shark No, I wouldn't say it's a flaw. Clojure simply uses a stricter definition of the word "associative" than I'm using here; my definition includes structures that map from keys to themselves, Clojure's definition does not. When I say "associative", Clojure says "works with the `get` function". There's nothing wrong with that; we just have two different terms for the same concept. I didn't use Clojure's specific terminology in my answer because the concepts I discuss there are not specific to Clojure.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. It just explains how the programmer typically uses these data structures. For me vectors and lists and even maps are very similar things. I see, what makes them different is the way how they are internally stored in memory and how performant the algorithms are and what immutability means to them. But this is all internal implementation details. Why is even the syntax so different? Why can a map not just be a vector (or list) of pairs.

Comment: @habrewning Sorry if the answer is unclear; I wrote it a long time ago! But you're right that in this context, what makes these data structures different are indeed "how performant the algorithms are"; while it's true that some aspects of this performance are "internal implementation details," the [_asymptotic_ performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is considered part of the interface/contract of the data structure, and is essential to deciding which data structure to use. If a map were just a list of pairs, constant-time operations would become linear.

Answer (score 2):

Sam's answer is excellent.  There is one more reason that it wouldn't make sense for lists to be functions:

Literal lists already have a different, very important role, so they can't also be treated as functions in the way that vectors are.

Let's start with a vector containing two functions, `partial` and `+`, and a number, `5`.  We can treat the vector as a function, as you know, to return the value indexed by its argument:

```
user=> ([partial + 5] 2)
5
```

So far, so good.  Suppose we want to use a list `(partial + 5)` in place of the vector, as you suggested, to return the value `5`.  Will we get an error message?  No!  But we won't get `5` as the result, either:

```
user=> ((partial + 5) 2)
7
```

What happened? `(partial + 5)` returned a function--the function that adds 5 to its single argument--and then this function was applied to the argument `2`.

When a list is evaluated, its first element is evaluated, and should return a function.  If the first element is a symbol, it's evaluated, and then the function that's its value is applied to the arguments, which are the other elements of the list.  If the first argument of a list is itself a list, then it is evaluated in the same way that it would be evaluated if it were at the top level.  The entire expression in that inner list should return a function, which will then be applied to the other elements of the outer list.

Since an inner list that's the first element of list that's being evaluated already has this role, it can't also play the kind of role that vectors that are first elements play.

Comment: I think u need to change your demon to ('(partial + 5) 2)

Comment: I didn't intend it to be quoted, and if it were, the code I gave wouldn't do what I said.  But you have a good point:  What's analogous to `([:a :b] 1)`, or `('[:a :b] 1)`, is `('(:a :b) 1)`, which generates an error.  Then I think Elogent's answer is relevant--especially about efficiency.  Accessing a vector entry is fast; it involves indexing or another fast method.  Accessing maps and sets is fast because they use hashing.  These access involves a simple calculation--like a simple function.  List access is slow because it can involve grabbing one pointer after another, over and over again.