# Why list can not act as function to get its indexed element in clojure?

Tags: list, clojure

Vector and map can act as function to get its elements from key

```
([1 2 3] 2) ;=> 3
({:a 1 :b 2} :a) ;=> 1
```

but why I can not do this for list?

```
('(1 2 3) 2)
;clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn(java.lang.ClassCastException)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did the designer make vector, map, and set functions in clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510969/why-did-the-designer-make-vector-map-and-set-functions-in-clojure)

Answer (score 5):

I think the error message is pretty descriptive in this case. Persistent list doesn't implement `IFn`, therefore cannot act as function. This is Clojure design choice and the reason may be that `List` datastructure is not designed for random access (getting element by index), because complexity of this operation is `O(n)`, which is much worse than vector's `O(log(n))`.